# How to get program fullscreen in dwm from spawn?

Tags: linux

I am a new user to dwm, and I start program in float layout in dwm,

but it seems the program does not get fullscreen, only take part of the screen
How can I get it fullscreen in the file "config.h"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tag window to tiling layout will get this problem fixed.

Actually most of the time, the float layout is not necessary.